# Count consecutives

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, count

I need to write a method that does the following

```
consecutive_count("aaabbcbbaaa") == [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

I got the code, but it looks ugly and I'm trying to see a better solution, please advice.

Here is my code:

```
def consecutive_count(str)

  el = str[0]; count = 0; result = []
  str.split("").each do |l|

    if (el != l)
      result << [el, count]
      count = 1
      el = l
    else
      count +=1
    end

  end
  result << [el, count] if !el.nil?

  return result

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way :

```
s = "aaabbcbbaaa"
s.chars.chunk{|e| e }.map{|item,ary| [item,ary.size]}
# => [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

Comment: Chunk in a great method!

Comment: This is again an example where I miss an `identity` function in the core library. I usually have something like `IDENTITY = -> x { x }` in my tool belt, which would then make your example something like `… .chunk(&IDENTITY).map …` It looks like Ruby 2.1 might gain an `Object#itself` method, so that you could do `… .chunk(&:itself).map …`

Comment: @JörgWMittag Do you like `s.chars.chunk(&:to_s).map{|item,ary| [item,ary.size]}`... If you like I will put it in my answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
"aaabbcbbaaa".scan(/(?<s>(?<c>.)\k<c>*)/).map{|s, c| [c, s.length]}
# => [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

or

```
"aaabbcbbaaa".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{|s, c| [c, s.length]}
# => [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexp solution:

```
my_s = "aaabbcbbaaa"
p  my_s.scan(/(.)(\1*)/).map{|x,y| [x, y.size + 1]}
#=> [["a", 3], ["b", 2], ["c", 1], ["b", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

or

```
a, result = "aaabbcbbaaa", []
result << a.slice!(/(\w)\1*/) until a.empty?
```

and then map the result with counts.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which does not involve regex magic (although those are a bit shorter and probably faster) is this:

```
str.each_char.each_with_object([]) do |char, result|
  if (result.last || [])[0] == char
    result.last[1] += 1
  else
    result << [char, 1]
  end
end
```

Depending on your level of understanding, it might better transport your intended meaning which might help to debug the thing in 6 month :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
def consecutive_count(str)
  result = {}
  array = str.split(//).uniq
  array.each.map {|char| result[char] = 0}
  array.each do |char|
    while str.starts_with?(char) do        
      result[char] += 1
      str[0] = ""
   end
  result
end
```